# Reset setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have problem with reset setTimeout. I tried use [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout):

```
function formMsg(text){

    if (text == "success"){
        $( ".alert-msg" ).removeClass( "hidden alert-danger" ).addClass( "alert-success" );
        $( ".alert-success .msg" ).html( "<b>Well done!</b> You successfully added order." );
    } else {
        $( ".alert-msg" ).removeClass( "hidden alert-success" ).addClass( "alert-danger" );
        $( ".alert-danger .msg" ).html( "<b>F***!</b> Something went wrong." );
    }

    window.clearTimeout(timer);

    var timer = window.setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $(".alert-msg").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $(this).addClass('hidden').show(0);
                    });
                }, 2000);

}
```

but with no result. I expect that when you click, the timer has measured two seconds again.

Comment: So what the issue are you facing ?

Comment: `timer` is a local variable inside the scope of your function. So on next click, the interval identifier create in the first click, won’t be available. You need to move the variable to an outer scope, that both “instances” of the handler function have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you initialize the variable as local (inside your function).
This will do the trick:

```
window.clearTimeout(formMsg.timer);
formMsg.timer = window.setTimeout(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

move the timer out of the function context like so:

```
var timer = null; //initialize    

function formMsg(text){

        if (text == "success"){
            $( ".alert-msg" ).removeClass( "hidden alert-danger" ).addClass( "alert-success" );
            $( ".alert-success .msg" ).html( "<b>Well done!</b> You successfully added order." );
        } else {
            $( ".alert-msg" ).removeClass( "hidden alert-success" ).addClass( "alert-danger" );
            $( ".alert-danger .msg" ).html( "<b>F***!</b> Something went wrong." );
        }

        if(timer !== null)
        window.clearTimeout(timer);

        var timer = window.setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $(".alert-msg").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                            $(this).addClass('hidden').show(0);
                        });
                    }, 2000);

    }
```